# Unwanted Base url is attached

Tags: codeigniter, tags, anchor, href, base-url

Let My ***baseurl*** is like: `http://abcd.com/`, I want to use anchor tag `<a href="<?php echo $result->url ?>"> Test Page </a>`

Here url is field name of database table which contain url `try.com`. I want to use that url.

When I click `Test Page` in browser it redirect to `http://abcd.com/try.com`

Here `abcd.com` is my baseurl and `try.com` is the value of table field.

How to remove automatic attached baseurl.

Comment: You want to redirect on which url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add two slashes before echoing the result url. i hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Ohh thanks. It was simple in fact. Can you please tell me how did `//` solve my problem?

Comment: one is relative path and other one is absolute path. please visit this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) .